# Can we determine the solution to $u_t+bu=u_{xx}$ given the solution to $u_t=u_{xx}$?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> If the solution to $$u_t=u_{xx}, \ \ u(x,0)=\phi(x)$$ is $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x-y)^2/4t}\phi(y) \ dy,$$ what is the solution to  $$u_t+bu=u_{xx}, \ \ u(x,0)=\phi(x) \tag{1}$$ where $b>0$ is a constant.

This problem reminds me of finding homogeneous and inhomogeneous solutions to simple ODEs. I though that $$u_t-u_{xx}=0,$$ could represent the homogeneous solution, $u_H(x,t)$, meaning we require a particular solution, $u_P(x,t)$, to $$u_t-u_{xx}=bu.$$ Hence the solution to $(1)$ is $u(x,t)=u_H(x,t)+u_P(x,t).$ I *hint* would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu(t)$ be an "integrating factor" such that

$$ \mu u_t + b\mu u = \big[\mu u\big]_t $$

Then the original PDE can be simplified to

$$ v_t = v_{xx} $$

where $v(x,t) = \mu(t) u(x,t)$

The first equation simplifies to $\mu' = b\mu$, or $\mu(t) = e^{bt}$

This is somewhat analogous to the first-order ODE

$$ y'(t) + by(t) = f(t) $$

Answer (score 5):

I guess the second equation is equivalent to 
$$
v_t = v_{xx}
$$
with $v(x,0)=\phi(x)$, where $v(x,t) = e^{bt}u(x,t)$.

Comment: Didn't see that coming. Are you able to explain this a bit more?

Comment: Substitute $v=e^{bt}u$ into $v_t = v_{xx}$ and you should get $u_t+bu=u_{xx}$.

Comment: Agreed. But is there a more intuitive reason why this works, rather than how it does work. How did you see that this would work?

Comment: It's just a nice property of the exponential function. In fact, in more general sense, if we have something of type $u_t+g'(t)u = u_{xx}$, the method might still work. One might show that the equation is equivalent to something of type $(e^{g(t)}u)_t = (e^{g(t)}u)_{xx}$. However, we need to make sure that the initial conditions are compatible, that is $e^{g(0)} = 1$ in our case.